# AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items' Python product in stock checker

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to use Python to create a program that checks if a product is in stock. If it is in stock it should print - 200, in stock. If its not, then 200, out of stock.

The program code I have used is based upon Arya Boudaie's code. Later on I will try to figure out how to get it to send me an email to let me know its in stock, hopefully.

The error I get is in the title: The highlighted part is the page variable, saying the set object has no attribute items.

full traceback is:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'set' object has no attribute 'items'
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\dyson2.py", line 7, in get_page_html
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\dyson2.py", line 19, in check_inventory
    page_html = get_page_html(url)
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\dyson2.py", line 26, in <module>
    check_inventory()
```

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

def get_page_html(URL):
    headers = {"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36"}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(page.status_code)
    return page.content


def check_item_in_stock(page_html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')
    out_of_stock_div = soup.find("div", {"id": "sold_out_text"})
    return out_of_stock_div.text == "In stock."

def check_inventory():
    url = "https://www.boots.com/dyson-v10-cyclone-animal-10267801" 
    page_html = get_page_html(URL)
    if check_item_in_stock(page_html):
        print("In stock")
    else:
        print("Out of stock")

while True:
    check_inventory()
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Could you fix the indentation on your code and share the full traceback

Comment: should be fixed now - full traceback is: Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'set' object has no attribute 'items'
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\dyson2.py", line 7, in get_page_html
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\dyson2.py", line 19, in check_inventory
    page_html = get_page_html(url)
  File "C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\dyson2.py", line 26, in <module>
    check_inventory()

Comment: I believe `headers` should be a dictionary.

Comment: Where did you get that `headers` line? You currently have it as a set containing a single string but I believe it's meant to be a dictionary.

Comment: The example given in the [documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) is `headers = {'user-agent': 'my-app/0.0.1'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you function `get_page_html(url)`, the key is missing in your `headers` definition, therefore it becomes a [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) (see examples in the docs), however, [`requests.get()`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.request) expects `headers` to be a [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) (which has an `items()` method).

If you change it to the following, it should work:

```py
def get_page_html(url):
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36"
#       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#       This is missing in your code.
    }
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(page.status_code)
    return page.content
```

(You also need to make sure that you use the same upper/lower case spelling for your variables. In the example you mixed `URL` and `url` which Python will see as two different variables.)